# Regex Non capturing group - Useless?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get my head around this concept, but I really can't see how it's useful, so I'm assuming I'm missing the point.

For example -

This regex `/([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?/` will match numbers with or without a 'st', 'rd' etc. suffix.

So `"1st".match(/([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?/g)` returns ["1st"]

`"1".match(/([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?/g)` returns ["1"]

However, this still works exactly the same **without** the (?:) par!

`"1st".match(/([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)?/g)` returns ["1st"]

Thanks...

Comment: Are you grabbing match 0 or match 1? Match 0 is the entire matched string, whereas match 1 is the first capture group. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC6jU1/1)

Comment: A group is a group. The difference is the *capturing* part. Since you are not using what the group captures, it appears to you as if there was no difference.

Comment: With ?: then match 1 is simply the number, and without it I also have match 2 which is "st". So w/ - 1st returns [1st, 1]. w/o - [1st, 1, st]. But why? I can't understand the difference...

Comment: *"But why?"* Because that's the purpose of the non-capturing group: It does not "capture" the part of the text it matched. `(?:st|nd|rd|th)` means "group `st|nd|rd|th` but don't capture the match". And as expected, `[1st, 1]` does not contain the match.

Comment: So what added value does it give us? I can't think of a scenario where I wouldn't want to catch it

Comment: sometimes you want to act on a group instead of a single context. also good for "".split...

Comment: @thomas: For exactly the reason you used it in the your expression: to group subexpression and act on them as a whole `(...)?`. *"I can't think of a scenario where I wouldn't want to catch it"* It's pretty simple really: The grouping operator does two things: It groups and it captures. If you are only interested in grouping, then you are using the non-capturing grouping operator. Is it really so hard to image a scenario where someone doesn't want to capture a certain part of the text?

Comment: What does `/[0-9]+((st)|(nd)|(rd)|(th))?()()()()/` match ? Is it the conclusion that capture groups are useless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-capture grouping is faster because the regex engine doesn't have to keep track of the match.  It can be a good idea not to capture what you don't need to capture for the sake of clarity.  For example:

```
(foo|bar)((z|q)s?)?
```

This is somewhat contrived, but you could easily apply it to a real regex.  You can match `fooz` or `foozs`.  We are interested in the `foo` and `bar` part as well as `z` or `q`, but we don't care about the optional `s`.  So which part is `z` or `q`?  Is it capture group 2 or 3?  Imagine if we had `(?:(z|q)` instead.  Now, we know there are only two capture groups so we don't have to make this mental jump.

---

Sometimes non-capturing is necessary such as for JavaScript's [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

> If separator contains capturing parentheses, matched results are returned in the array.

If you want to use grouping for splits but you don't want to include the split regex in the array, you *must* use non-capturing groups.

Comment: I agree with @ExplosionPills, but also want to add, it is also useful for the sanity of the programmer if using back references or reference in replace.  If you only use capturing groups where you need to reference adding additional groups are far less likely to change your reference numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see a difference because your regex has the [*global* flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global), which when using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will only yield an array with all results from the whole string. Try this (without `g`) instead:

```
> "1st".match(/([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?/)
["1st", "1"]
> "1".match(/([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?/)
["1", "1"]
> "1st".match(/([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)?/)
["1st", "1", "st"]
```

Using the [`exec` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) would have the same behaviour.

Comment: that's the real factor involved. I was trying to search it I know that Non-capturing groups doesn't capture, it does used for match.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful when you have very complex regexes with many capturing groups, and you don't want to clutter your code with groups that solely exist for structuring the regexp. You want to avoid the "Group 1 is data A, group 2 is data B, groups 3 and 4 are junk, group 5 is data C" scenario.

Non-capturing groups are also slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

From python 're' documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.