# Regex for matching specific URL with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I have the following regex pattern

`const pattern = /^\/(abc|def|something\/thisone|en|ppp){1}/i;`

`const mat = pattern.exec(myURL);`

Here How do I change the above pattern so that it wont match `something/thisone` but when it is followed by any params like so: `something/thisone/<anystring/number>` ..?

Tried:

`const pattern = /^\/(abc|def|something\/thisone\/.*|en|ppp){1}/i;`

`const pattern = /^\/(abc|def|something\/thisone\/.+|en|ppp){1}/i;`

Nothing seems to work..

Valid urls:

`www.mysite.com/abc/`

`www.mysite.com/abc`

`www.mysite.com/def/`

`www.mysite.com/something/thisone/whatever`
`www.mysite.com/something/thisone/whatever/`
`www.mysite.com/something/thisone/whatever?u=90`

Comment: add your valid urls.

Comment: www.mysite.com/abc;  www.mysite.com/something/thisone/p2edn3; @ AZ_

Comment: and `www.mysite.com/something/thisone` is invalid?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: Could you provide few sample strings in the question

Answer (score 0):

After viewing added examples, knowing that OP does not want to capture anything, let's simplify this to:

```
www\.mysite\.com\/(?:abc|def|something\/thisone(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+)\/?
```

Explanation:

```
www\.mysite\.com         # match www.mysite.com
\/                       # followed by `/`
(?:                      # non-capturing group 1
  abc                    # 'abc'
  |                      # OR
  def                    # 'def'
  |                      # OR
  something\/thisone     # 'something/thisone' followed by
  (?:                    # non-capturing group 2
    \/                   # '/' 
    [^\/\s]+             # 1 or more chars, not '/' or space
  )+                     # END group 2. 1 or more times.
)                        # END group 1
\/?                      # optional closing /
```

For examples: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/X4u9u1/6)

Comment: The above matches if I have only 1 string after `thisone` - after `thisone` it can be anything is the requirement here, thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Ok. I'll adapt the regex so it can be repeatable.

Comment: better make the group non-capturing `/abc|def|something\/thisone(?:\/[0-9a-z]+)+/`

Comment: There is nothing about capturing in the OPs question, only about matching. So, whether or not to capture is better, is answering a different question.

Comment: it's better to do so when not required. [Regex Non capturing group - Useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251159/regex-non-capturing-group-useless)

Comment: That's all true. But again: we don't know from the question what OP is going to do with the result. I'll adapt the answer to make both cases explicit.

Comment: this does not seem to work `\/something\/thisone(\/([a-z]+|[0-9]+))+` - my url: `www.mysite.com/something/thisone/somename/ ` does not validate -i am basically trying to see if the above url for example should be valid with my pattern

Comment: So it should be possible to end with a `/`. Updated regex and regex101.

Comment: but it wont support urls like: www.mysite.com/something/thisone/mmm-nnn/?u=preview

Comment: Cleaned up the answer, using all examples given.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`const pattern = /^\/(abc|def|something\/thisone\/[0-9a-zA-Z]*){1}/i;`

The pattern `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` should match any number of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Did not work for some reason, not sure none of the patterns seem to work that are straight forward - like for my url: www.mysite.com/something/thisone/ppp does not match

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple regex expression.

```js
let regex = /.*something\/thisone\/.+/g

let string1 = 'something/thisone/acd';
let string2 = 'something/thisone/abc/';
let string3 = 'something/thisone';
let string4 = 'https://somedomain/something/thisone/123';

console.log(string1.match(regex));
console.log(string2.match(regex));
console.log(string3.match(regex));
console.log(string4.match(regex));
```